# Javascript problems with IE, and Prototype 1.6.0.3

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox, prototypejs

The code below works perfectly fine with Firefox, however, I am having problems with IE 8... and 7... instead of populating the select's with the options returned from my php script (like it does in FireFox) it is doing nothing in IE.

I have narrowed the problem down to $('city').innerHTML -- works in Firefox not IE.

Any ideas?

This is in my header:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/prototype-1.6.0.3.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/scriptaculous.js'></script>
```

The HTML code (resides in the body)

```
--snip--
<select id="city">
</select>
--snip--
```

The JavaScript this gets triggered from the Prov/State onChange (which works on IE and FF)

```
--snip--
$('city').innerHTML = "<option value='test'> This is a test";
--snip--
```

Comment: wait - so does it or doesn't it work in IE?

Comment: edited, sorry about that confusion

Comment: Are you sure onChange is working in IE?

Comment: just $('city').innerHTML is not working, or $('city') is also not working?

Comment: $('city').innerHTML = "anything" - works in Firefox, not IE.  What debugger should I be using for IE?

Comment: onChange is working- the stuff inside the <select> gets wiped out, however it does not load my options, as it does in FF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using update() instead?

```
$('city').update("<option value='test'>This is a test</option>");
```

Comment: Yup, update exists for this reason. $('city').insert({bottom: '<option value="foo">foo</option>'}) as well, if I recall.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a [known bug:](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276228) that [still hasn't been resolved](http://alexle.net/archives/150).

You can't reliably set the innerHTML of a select element in ie.

Workarounds include setting the innerHTML of the entire select element (by setting the parent's innerHTML), or creating and appending individual option elements.

Comment: Added the </option> tag, made no difference in either case.

Comment: Nonsense, it makes no difference whether you use single quotes or double quotes, and option tags don't have to be closed.

Comment: Yepppppper... I just wrapped it in a DIV, and return an entire <SELECT><OPTIONS></SELECT>... works now... I hate IE...